# How to create AccessKey for AzureAD Application using terraform

Tags: azure-active-directory, terraform

I'm currently using Terraform to setup my Azure infrastructure and am currently wondering how to create AccessKeys for an AzureAD Application using Terraform.

I created an AzureAD App with the azurerm provider like this:

```
resource "azurerm_azuread_application" "test" {
  name                       = "App"
  homepage                   = "localhost:8042"
  available_to_other_tenants = false
  oauth2_allow_implicit_flow = false
}
```

I'm able to find this application in my AD and am able to create keys using the AzurePortal UI. But how would I be able to create such keys using terraform if at all?

Comment: If my reply is helpful or not, may be you could let me know?

Answer (score 1):

The key of the AD application in the portal is also the password of the service principal. If you create an application, it will automatic create a service principal. For more details about Azure ad application and service principal, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals). Besides, you could find the service principal in the portal, **Azure Active Directory** -> **Enterprise applications**, its name is the same with the AD App.

So you could use [azurerm_azuread_service_principal_password](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/azuread_service_principal_password.html) to do it.

```
resource "azurerm_azuread_application" "test" {
  name                       = "example"
  homepage                   = "http://homepage"
  identifier_uris            = ["http://uri"]
  reply_urls                 = ["http://replyurl"]
  available_to_other_tenants = false
  oauth2_allow_implicit_flow = true
}

resource "azurerm_azuread_service_principal" "test" {
  application_id = "${azurerm_azuread_application.test.application_id}"
}

resource "azurerm_azuread_service_principal_password" "test" {
  service_principal_id = "${azurerm_azuread_service_principal.test.id}"
  value                = "VT=uSgbTanZhyz@%nL9Hpd+Tfay_MRV#"
  end_date             = "2020-01-01T01:02:03Z"
}
```